# federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb code error

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I use tensorflow-federated learning api.
And recently, I update tensorflow-federated to 0.8.0 version.
And then I run the federated_learning_for_image_classification.ipynb file.
But It did not work on "`state = iterative_process.initialize()`" code line.

Some error is happened I can not do next.

Why was it happened? Previous version of federated api 0.6.0 was working great.

you can refer to the below code and error picture.

```
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()

from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import collections

import warnings
from six.moves import range
import numpy as np
import six
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_federated as tff

warnings.simplefilter('ignore');

tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior();

np.random.seed(0);

if six.PY3:
tff.framework.set_default_executor(tff.framework.create_local_executor());

tff.federated_computation(lambda: 'Hello, World!')();

emnist_train, emnist_test = tff.simulation.datasets.emnist.load_data();

len(emnist_train.client_ids);

print(emnist_train.client_ids, emnist_test.client_ids);

emnist_train.output_types, emnist_train.output_shapes;

example_dataset = emnist_train.create_tf_dataset_for_client(
emnist_train.client_ids[0]);

example_element = iter(example_dataset).next();

example_element['label'].numpy();

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt;
plt.imshow(example_element['pixels'].numpy(), cmap='gray', aspect='equal');
plt.grid('off')
_ = plt.show()

NUM_CLIENTS = 5
NUM_EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 20
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 500

def preprocess(dataset):

  def element_fn(element):
    return collections.OrderedDict([
        ('x', tf.reshape(element['pixels'], [-1])),
        ('y', tf.reshape(element['label'], [1])),
    ])

  return dataset.repeat(NUM_EPOCHS).map(element_fn).shuffle(
  SHUFFLE_BUFFER).batch(BATCH_SIZE)

preprocessed_example_dataset = preprocess(example_dataset)

sample_batch = tf.nest.map_structure(
    lambda x: x.numpy(), iter(preprocessed_example_dataset).next())

sample_batch

def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
  return [preprocess(client_data.create_tf_dataset_for_client(x))
      for x in client_ids]

sample_clients = emnist_train.client_ids[0:NUM_CLIENTS]

print(sample_clients)

federated_train_data = make_federated_data(emnist_train, sample_clients)

len(federated_train_data), federated_train_data[0]

def create_compiled_keras_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(
          10, activation=tf.nn.softmax, kernel_initializer='zeros', 
input_shape=(784,))])

  model.compile(
      loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
      optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
      metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
  return model

def model_fn():
  keras_model = create_compiled_keras_model()
  return tff.learning.from_compiled_keras_model(keras_model, sample_batch)

iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn)

str(iterative_process.initialize.type_signature)

state = iterative_process.initialize()
```

[error picture-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3vGe.png)

[error picture-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL5qo.png)

Answer (score 1):

You must add these lines in notebook:

```
tff.framework.set_default_executor(tff.framework.create_local_executor(n)) 
tff.framework.set_default_executor(tff.framework.create_local_executor())
```

Where n is the number of clients in the local executor.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the Github issue [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/764); essentially, master is out of sync with the pip package. If you explicitly set the number of clients in the local executor, this should resolve itself.

Thanks for your interest in TFF!